# Send back data to the browser using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have the following code, codeigniter, which sent an email notification

```
  public function add__email_notification () {
    $message_body = $this->load->view('content/emailer/new_user', $data, TRUE);
    $this->email_notification($this->input->post('email'), $message_body);
    $result['result'] = "Notification Sent";
    echo json_encode($result);
  }
```

I would like this part of the function,

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

to send back data to the browser using ajax, and the ajax code is

```
$.ajax({
  type : 'POST',
  url : result.url,
  data : {
    'email' : result.email
  },
  dataType : 'JSON',
  success : function (e) {
    console.log(e);
  },
  error : function (e) {}
});
```

But the problem with this approach, it doesn't return json data to be determine on this part

```
  success : function (e) {
    console.log(e);
  },
```

of ajax.

Does anybody know how to?

Comment: What does it send back to javascript? Nothing or something else

Comment: Just nothing, I'm trying to trace line by line on dev tool, but yes there nothing.

Comment: I suspect, it's because of the email function

Comment: Are you sure that the PHP script is actually getting run

Comment: Yes, Actually I used debuger to trace php data

Comment: Well in that case, comment out the first 2 lines and just run the array create and json_encode to see what comes back then

Comment: Check "Network" tab in developer tools (F12 in chrome). Your ajax call will show there, and look at repsponse to determine is there any JSON object text there or maybe some server error.

Comment: Yes I do that everytime, That's why I'm wondering

Comment: And what's server response code? Because if it's other than 200, it may cause error call instead of success.

Comment: The response is 200

Comment: comment out everything else in the function and just send something like `echo json_encode("test")` and see if you can see that in the response. You said you're sure that the PHP script is running, but are you sure the specific function add__email_notification () is being executed?

Comment: what is you result.url?

Comment: Use exit; after echo json_encode()